# Data drinking alcohol in ten forward

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-generations

In Star Trek genarations, data is seen drinking alcohol which he hates, how is he able to taste and consume it, I remember form a previous episode in the series he is not able to consume food or liquid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that scene in particular, he had previously installed Lore's emotion chip which is what causes the reaction

In the Season 1 episode "Datalore" - Lore "spikes" a drink that incapacitates Data. Data and Lore both seem to accept that they can drink.

(this is just the music but a still from the scene is visible)

From the episode Deja Q:

```
                    Q
        What do I ask for? I've never
        eaten before.

                DATA
        The choice of meal is determined
        by individual tastes.

                Q
        What do you like?

                DATA
        Although I do not require
        sustenance, I occasionally ingest
        a semi-organic nutrient suspension
        in a silicon-based liquid medium.

They sit at the bar.

                Q
        Is it good?

                DATA
        It would be more accurate to
        say it is "good for me" as it
        lubricates my bio-functions.
```

Comment: Yeah I know that, still doesn't explain how he can consume it

Comment: @Darren edited with more info - an episode seems to indicate that he does have the capability to ingest things explicitly to support his function, so I would question the validity of the question itself since he is shown to consume. Do you have a reference to him saying he cannot?

Comment: So how would he dispose of it

Comment: @Darren - that's a different question than the one you posted ;) - here is an existing thread to that effect - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29177/what-happens-to-the-food-that-commander-data-digests-or-drinks - I lean towards agreeing with the last comment on the page from Xantec

Comment: Well it's connected to the same question, it's something to with how he consumes it

Answer (score 5):

The (kinda canon, kinda not) supplement to the [official Trek RPG game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Role_Playing_Game) has a schematic of Cmdr Data's upper body. As you can see from the labelled diagram, his chest cavity includes a "digestive enhancer" (with a label that goes behind his body to where his anus would be), strongly implying that he can ingest food and drink as well as disposing of it in a convincingly human fashion.

[image]

Comment: Nice.  And will ya look at that...his central power cavity is just a wee bit off center and to the left, like the human heart.  :-)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Data "goes to the bathroom."

Comment: Data may not, but his "mother," Juliana O'Donnell, probably does.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - Soong was very keen for Data to have the appearance of a human including sexuality, realistic hair and some sort of digestive system

Comment: @T-1000'sSon Was _anyone_ in Star Trek TNG ever seen going to the bathroom?

Comment: @Xantec: His mother would also need to be able to properly digest and utilize "normal" meals, otherwise her own suspension of disbelief that she's human would be lost.

Comment: No, but Data is an android, who doesn't require food, water, or sleep. To think that he needs to expel waste like humanoids do seems ludicrous to me.

Comment: @Ellesedil She would just need a method to break down food and convert it into waste similar to how human waste appears. A micro-replicator could probably do that.